# C++/CLI : Casting from unmanaged enum to managed enum

Tags: enums, casting, c++-cli, native, managed

What is the correct way of casting (in C++/CLI) from a native code `enum` to a managed code `enum` which contain the same `enum` values? Is there any difference with using the C# way of casting like for example `(int)` in C++/CLI.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Assuming your native code is

```
enum shape_type_e
{
    stUNHANDLED     = 0,            //!< Unhandled shape data.
    stPOINT         = 1             //!< Point data.
    ...
};
```

and your managed code is

```
public enum class ShapeType
{
    Unhandled   = 0,
    Point       = 1,
    ...
};
```

You can cast from the native to the managed using

```
shape_type_e nativeST = stPOINT;
ShapeType managedST = static_cast<ShapeType>(nativeST);
Debug.Assert(managedST == ShapeType::Point);
```

I always use `static_cast`, not the C# way of casting.

Comment: From the above code, I suppose you are casting from native to managed enum. What about the other way round from managed to native?

Comment: Static cast is your friend both ways ...

    nativeST = static_cast<shape_type_e>(managedST);

Comment: Based on your comment to @Lopper, could you then change the text in your answer to clarify that the example is demonstrating native-to-managed (and not the other way around as it currently states).

Answer (score 1):

It depends. for example, if you have a CLI enum that has an underlying type of ushort, it cannot hold a vallue of 257. By default the CLI enum is based on int, which should be fine in most cases. If your native C++ code use unsigned 32bit ints/64bit ints as the underlying type if enums, switch the base of your CLI enum to UInt32, long or ulong.

Comment: I won't have this issue because both enum are of type int. But which type of cast should be used in this case? Should it be const_cast, static_cast, dynamic_cast, reinterpret_cast, safe_cast or just the C# cast (an example is (int))?