# Using enum in c++ and c# via c++ header

Tags: c#, c++

I've got a server written in C++ that sits at the end of a named pipe, um, serving things. The commands which can be sent to the server are defined in an enum which is located in a header file.

```
enum {
    e_doThing1,
    e_doThing2
    ...
    e_doLastThing
};
```

The value of the desired enum is put into the first byte of messages sent to the server so it knows what to do. I am now writing a C# client which needs access to the services.

Is there any way I can include the header into the C# code so I don't have to maintain the same list in two locations?

Thanks,
Patrick

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sharing an enum from C#, C++/CLI, and C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240263/sharing-an-enum-from-c-c-cli-and-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were to put the enum in a namespace and give it a name, you could probably just add the header file directly to the C# project.

Edited with final solution:
That way around won't work, but the reverse will - name the header a .cs and include in C# project, then #include from C++.

Comment: Nice idea, you don't need the namespace but you do need to rename the file as a *.cs otherwise the compiler doesn't see the enum (the enum already had a name). Shame it couldn't be that simple :(

Comment: @Patrick: Nothing stops the C++ compiler #including a .cs file.

Answer (score 1):

Can you generate a copy of the file with an automated process like a pre-build step defined on the C# project?  All you need to do is create a copy of the file that adds a name between "enum" and "{", I think.

**Edit:** Depending on what kind of interface your C++ server exposes, .NET may even be able to automatically generate an interface file.  For example, if this enum were defined in a COM interface or a .NET remoting interface, I think there would be automatic means of generating the enum on the client based on the server's compiled code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use managed C++ for that. Include the header in a managed C++ project and you can use it from C#.

Answer (score 0):

You can use macro definition like this:
on C# wrapper:

```
public enum class eAlgId
 {
   ENUM_PARAMETERS
 };
```

on cpp:

```
enum ProcAlgID
{
 ENUM_PARAMETERS 
};
```

and on .h file that is known to both:

#define ALG_ENUM_PARAMETERS \

et1 = 0, et2, et3, et4