# How to expose constants from unmanaged C++ to C#

Tags: c++, c++-cli

Basically I need to expose several constants from unmanaged C++ to my C# library. The following approach works, but I think it smells:

In my unmanaged C++ code:

```
class Mappings
{
public:
    static const int North = 0 ;
    static const int West = 1 ;
    static const int East = 2 ;
    static const int South = 3 ;
```

In my managed C++ layer:

```
public:
    static const int North = Mappings::North ;
    static const int West = Mappings::West ;
    static const int East = Mappings::East ;
    static const int South = Mappings::South ;
```

Is there a cleaner/shorter way, so that I do not have to duplicate my code twice?

Comment: First off, those are not enums.

Comment: @parapura rajkumar: I'd rather not duplicate my code twice, it smells

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sharing an enum from C#, C++/CLI, and C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240263/sharing-an-enum-from-c-c-cli-and-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `public enum class` keywords to declare a managed enumeration type.  And yes, this is ugly since you cannot export the native C++ enumeration.  Repeating yourself is unfortunately required.

C++11 adopted the `enum class` keyword as well but it is still distinct from the managed version.  This caused a syntax ambiguity in C++/CLI since both language flavors now use the same keywords.  The compiler can see the distinction from the accessibility keyword (use `public` or `private`), it is not valid for native C++.

Comment: Repeating yourself is NOT required, the same source code can be used for all.